# Nextjs 13 - invariant expected app router to be mounted

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My initial project was Next12, migrate to Next13 makes this problem.

If I try to return the 404 page to the failed fetch.

I doubt the folder structure.

```
...
/app
./-(main)
./--page.tsx // if fail to fetch data on this page
./...
./-layout.tsx
...
```

layout.tsx

```
....

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const headerWidgets = await fetchWidgets(WidgetLocations.HEADER)
  const footerWidgets = await fetchWidgets(WidgetLocations.FOOTER)
  return (
    <html lang="sr">
      <body className="home">
        <Providers headerWidgets={headerWidgets} footerWidgets={footerWidgets}>
          <main className="main cart">
            <ToastContainer />
            {children}
          </main>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

error is here:

```
> 47 | const router = useRouter()
```

This is inside one of providers inside `<Provider>` comp in `layout.tsx`

page.tsx

```
const Home = async () => {
  const pageData = await getPageData("homepage", false)

  if (!pageData) {
    return notFound() // fatal is here!
  }

  return <>{pageData?.blocks && <BlocksWrapper blocks={pageData.blocks} />}</>
}

export default Home
```

Any idea?